# Transforming 0x byte endparts into actual values

Tags: php, byte

I have hardware unit, that when requested some data, returns a string, that when exploded on space, returns array of values:

```
$bytes = array(
    '03',
    '80',
    'A0',
    '01'    // and others, total of 240 entries
);
```

These actually, depict bytes: `0x03`, `0x80`, `0xA0`, `0x01`. I need to transform them into their actual values.

I have tried in a loop, to: `$value = 0x{$byte}`, `$value = {'0x' . $byte}` and others, to no avail.

Also tried `unpack`, but don't know what format to apply, am kind of clueless about bytes.

Seems like a basic issue, yet cannot wrap my head around it.

How can I dynamically, transform them into their actual integer values?

Comment: These are hex numbers. You want the decimal equivalents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [chr](http://www.php.net/chr) if you want a string

```
$value = chr($byte);
```

use [hexdec](http://www.php.net/hexdec) if you want an integer

```
$value = hexdec($byte);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, bytes are the same as one-character long strings, with the following escaping:

```
$byte = "\x03";
```

There is a function that can help you, which is [chr()](https://www.php.net/chr).
This function take as parameter the ASCII code of the byte you want to obtain. As it can be either a numeric string or an integer, you can use

```
$code = "03";
$byte = chr("0x" . $code);
```

to obtain the `'\x03'` byte, with the parameter to chr being interpreted as an hexadecimal integer.

On the other hand, as mentionned by @chumkiu, if you are trying to obtain integer values, the following code will work:

```
$code = "03";
$int = hexdec($code);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this will be sufficient:

```
foreach($bytes as byte)
{
    echo hexdec($byte);
}
```

See also the [hexdec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) manual.

Answer (score 0):

If `$string` is the raw data (hex digits separated by spaces), then you can extract the binary data like this:

```
$binary = pack('H*',str_replace(' ','',$string));
```